# I need help understanding this proof about convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

[image]

The proof says that we used the fact that

$(1-\epsilon)^\frac{x}{\epsilon} \rightarrow e^{-x}$ Why is this so? How do I prove this?

Also, why do we need the fact that $\lfloor x/p_n \rfloor - x/p_n$ is bounded?

Thanks

Comment: That's one of the earliest definitions of the exponential function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$(1-p_n)^{\lfloor x/p_n \rfloor} = (1-p_n)^{x/p_n} (1-p_n)^{\lfloor x/p_n \rfloor - x/p_n}$$
For the first factor, we use the fact that $(1-\epsilon)^{x/\epsilon} \to e^{-x}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.  This is a standard fact from calculus and there are many ways to check it.  Note that we can write $(1-\epsilon)^{x/\epsilon} = \left((1-\epsilon)^{1/\epsilon}\right)^x$ so it is sufficient to show $(1-\epsilon)^{1/\epsilon} \to e^{-1}$.  In some developments, it is essentially the definition of $e$, but from a mechanical point of view, you can also take natural logs and use L'Hospital's rule.

For the second factor, we use the fact that $\lfloor x/p_n \rfloor - x/p_n$ is bounded.  Indeed, $-1 \le \lfloor x/p_n \rfloor - x/p_n \le 0$ so we can write $$ (1-p_n)^0 \le (1-p_n)^{\lfloor x/p_n \rfloor - x/p_n} \le (1-p_n)^{-1}.$$  Now use the squeeze theorem to conclude that this converges to 1.

Comment: I think you want to write $(1-\epsilon)^{x/\epsilon} \to e^x$ rather than $(1-\epsilon)^{x/\epsilon} \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @tom: $e^{-x}$ actually. Fixed, thanks.